# C++ socket programming with multiple keep-alive connections

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am designing a backend server for some messaging protocol. In the program, there is one master server and multiple servers (which I will call secondary servers). The master server is in charge of keeping data consistency between secondary servers so the master server needs to be connected to all the secondary servers constantly (keep-alive).

As I'm using C++, I'm using socket programming. The main role of the master server is to listen to the requests made by the secondary servers and occasionally serve information to them. I don't know which of the two methods below will fit my program more:

1. Spawn a thread for each secondary server connection in the beginning so that each thread is constantly listening to the secondary server it's connected to. Keep it alive, and whenever the master server needs to serve data to the secondary servers, spawn a new thread (or maybe use thread pool for this?) to handle the task.
2. Main thread initially connects to all the secondary servers. Using select() (or poll()), the main thread listens to all connections simultaneously and whenever a new request is made from the secondary server, use thread pool to handle the task.

Comment: Why not implement both methods very simply, and then stress-test them using requests representative of your expected connection workloads.  You can then collect whatever performance metrics you are concerned about, and use those to make an informed decision about which approach is more suitable to your requirements.

Comment: There is a good chance, that all the multi threading will not scale well. My experience is, that having a single thread for a server application can be much faster as having worker or connection threads. Especially if you like to have for each connection a single thread, you waste a lot of your system resources. No idea how much load your requests generate, but if it is only getting some data from a data pool, a single thread can be the fastest solution. We tried a lot with MQTT like server/client architecture. Single threaded was 5 times faster as multi threaded on a 6 core PC. Measure!!!!

Comment: @Klaus As a matter of fact, I'm building a broker server for MQTT. Thanks for the recommendation.